# When is $a+b\leq ab$, a and b are positive real numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Is this true!

Given $a,b>0$, real numbers, then $$a+b\leq ab$$
If not, when this could be true?

Comment: Clearly, if $a=1$ or $b=1$, it can't be true. You then check the cases of, say, $a > 1$ and $a < 1$...

Comment: Just an interesting comment. This can be extended to complex numbers too. See $(1+i)+(1-i)=(1+i)(1-i)$ and $2=2$.

Comment: $(a_1+a_2i)+(b_1+b_2i) \leq (a_1+a_2i)(b_1+b_2i)$

$(a_1+b_1)+(a_2+b_2)i \leq (a_1b_1-a_2b_2)+(a_1b_2+a_2b_1)i$

$(a_1+b_1-a_1b_1+a_2b_2)+(a_2+b_2-a_1b_2-a_2b_1)i \leq 0$

But, this inequation just holds if $(a_2+b_2-a_1b_2-a_2b_1)=0$ and we have too $(a_1+b_1-a_1b_1+a_2b_2) \leq 0$

Answer (score 13):

Rewrite the inequality as $(a-1)(b-1) \ge 1$. Now can you take it from here?

**Comment:** One could call the idea *completing the rectangle*. It is a lot less useful than completing the square!

Answer (score 2):

You could show the inequality graphically as 
below[image: plot]

Note: White space correspond to x, y values not satisfying the inequality

Answer (score 0):

I assume $a$ and $b$ are both positive real numbers, $a+b\leq ab$.

Suppose $a>1$ then $a-1>0$ from $a+b\leq ab$, $ab-b\geq a$

So, $b(a-1)\geq a$. That is $b\geq a/(a-1)$.

Comment: if $a=0.5, b=0.5$ then $1> ab=0.25$!

Comment: @Monica, check my proof, I have cleared my mistake.